# JSP - Microsoft ODBC - Microsoft Access Driver Could not find file '(unknown)'

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, ms-access, jdbc

I am new to JSP. So i want to make a login web, but I stuck with the sql exception. Annyone know how to solve this? All program i use is 32bit, and I already add Ms Access Database to my user data sources.

here is the error information :

```
5: <%
6:  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
7:  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/db.accdb"));
8:  Statement st = con.createStatement(1004,1008);
9: 
10: %>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:916)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:845)
    org.apache.jsp.khema.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:145)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
root cause

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file '(unknown)'.
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6957)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7114)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3073)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
    org.apache.jsp.khema.doLogin_jsp._jspService(doLogin_jsp.java:72)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Comment: You could have your scriptlet spit out the value of `application.getRealPath("WEB-INF/db.accdb")` and see if the database file really does exist there. (It appears not.) You also might want to check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/2144390).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a start make sure that you specified the correct path to the DB file, once you do that do the following steps.
 from the Control panel search for  Administrative tools then search for  Data Sources(ODBC) after that  Add `Microsoft Access Drivers(*mdb,*accdb)`.